# format value combogrid jquery eui

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I dont know how to change format combogrid jquery eui.

in tutor the function like this

```
$.fn.datebox.defaults.formatter = function(date){
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var m = date.getMonth()+1;
    var d = date.getDate();
    return m+'/'+d+'/'+y;
}
```

My combogrid like this,

```
    <input type="text" name="tgl_buat_ticket" class="easyui-datebox" 
required="true" size="53" data-options="dateFormat:'yyyy-mm-dd'"/>
```

Anyone can help me..
Thanks for attention and reply..

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to set your date as you want using `dateFormat` option:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

So you code will look like:

```
$(".yourselector").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
```

Happy coding!